# array sort alphabetic order into dropdown javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a empty dropdown list and a array however i want to display my array in my dropdown list in alphabetic order. How can i achieve this ?

```
<select id="dropdown">
</select>

var array = ["vintage","frames","treats","engraved", "stickers", "jewelerybox", "flask"];
```

Comment: simply `array.sort();` will work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["vintage","frames","treats","engraved", "stickers", "jewelerybox", "flask"];

array.sort(function(val1 , val2){
  return val1.localeCompare(val2);
});

console.log(array); // ["engraved", "flask", "frames", "jewelerybox", "stickers", "treats", "vintage"]
```